# base 64 encode a form file

Tags: php, javascript, forms, html, fileapi

I'm writing a *very* simple file sharing site in JS and PHP. I've got a drag/drop working, so the browser gets a `file` object upon drop, and from there I tried to send in a `xhr` request to an upload page. However, I can't seem to just drop a binary `file` object in a request header, and so was wondering how I'd go about base64 encoding it.

In PHP I'd use `base64_encode`, but I'm not even at the PHP page yet. Maybe you could suggest an alternative method to my current one?

Oh, and in the PHP that receives it, it writes to a semi-random file after `base64_decode`ing the file.

EDIT: I worked around it, but there isn't really a good answer. Thanks for helping!

Here's my demo: http://bernsteinbear.com/up

Answer (score 3):

There is a function in the works that is currently only supported in Firefox, `xhr.sendAsBinary`, but for now you can do the Base64 encoding in Javascript with this custom function:

http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-base64.html

Alternatively, you can implement `sendAsBinary` yourself, as seen here:

http://hublog.hubmed.org/archives/001941.html

Just be aware that the Base64 method is currently the most compatible method.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you aren't using something like the [Valumns File Uploder](http://github.com/valums/file-uploader)?  I don't know why you're wanting to add a binary file "as a request header" (that makes little sense to me), but having to base64 encode it before sending seems a bit silly when HTTP can handle sending binary data in both directions quite easily ([example with forms](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html)).  Then again, I'm unfamiliar with the File API, so I'm not sure what special things you might be doing with it (are you transforming the file at all before sending?).  Maybe I'm missing the point of this exercise.